# Structure-Padding and Size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code.

1. The problem is that as you can see, I get those blue lines in the links area and I tend to think it's from the padding used for read-more and I can't understand why they appear and how to remove them.

I also have another misunderstanding.
2. Why does the green border (.middle) have that size? No size is set in the code.Its parent is background-blur, but its size is set in the code for the whole screen.

3. If a child is sized with vw, its size depends on the size of the entire viewport, or the father's viewport, because I played with these units and not always an element with 50vw is equal to another element with 50vw.

In this snippet, I used vw and sometimes 5vw seems very much and sometimes very little and I don't understand why.

```js
const hamburger_menu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

hamburger_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{

  min-height:100vh;

   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #485461 0%, #28313b 74%);
   width:100%;
}

.navbar{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:3rem;

  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;

}

.logo{
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 5vw 2vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  color:white;
  z-index:1;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;


}

.middle{
background:green;
}

.menu{
  max-width:60rem;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;

}

.hamburger-menu{
  cursor: pointer;
  width:4em;
  height:3rem;

  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;


  z-index:1;
}


.container.active .menu-bar{
  background:transparent;
  transform:rotate(360deg);

}

.container.active .menu-bar:before{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  transition:0.3s ease-in-out;
  background:cyan;
}

.container.active .menu-bar:after{
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transition:0.3s ease-in-out;
  background:cyan;
}

.container.active .main{
    transition:2s ease-in-out ;
    transform: perspective(120vw) rotateY(20deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(20vw);
}

.container.active .main:hover  {
  transition:2s ease-in-out ;
  transform: perspective(150vw) rotateY(20deg) scale(.35) translateZ(30vw);
}


.container.active .main:hover #water:hover {
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}

.container.active .main:hover #water{
  color:cyan;
  position:relative;
}


.container.active .background-blur{
  background:transparent;
}

.container.active .logo{
   color:white;
  animation:animate-logo ;
  animation-duration:8s;
}

.menu-bar{
  width:50%;
  height:1.5px;
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.menu-bar:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:1.5px;
  background:white;
  transform:translateY(-7px);

}


.menu-bar:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:1.5px;
  background:white;
  transform:translateY(7px);

}

.main{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100vh;


top:0;
left:0;
transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
transform:translate3d();
transform-origin:left;
}


.background{
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: url("time.jpg") no-repeat top center  / 100% 100%;

  transition:0.5s ease-in-out;

}



.container.active .shadow1{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:95%;
  height:85%;
  right:15%;
  transition:2s ease-in-out;


  transform: perspective(10vw) rotateY(20deg)  translateZ(90%);
  background:white;
  opacity:0.15;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: left;
  animation:animate-shadow1 2s ease-in-out;

}

.container.active .shadow2{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-2;
  width:95%;
  height:95%;
  right:10%;
  transition:2s ease-in-out;

  transform: perspective(10vw) rotateY(20deg)  translateZ(90%);
  background:white;
  opacity:0.1;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: left;

}

.background-blur{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: rgba(43, 51, 59, 0.8);
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;

}

.read-more{
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  padding:0.6rem 0.2rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  border-radius:25px;
  background:blue;
  transform:translateX(-3.6vw);

}

.links{
  position:absolute;

  top:20%;
  left:160%;
  list-style: none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:stretch;
  align-content: space-around;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.container.active .links{
  visibility:visible;
  animation:menu-anime 5s linear ;

  font-size:3vw;

}
.links a {
  text-decoration:none;


  font-size:250%;
  color:white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position:relative;
  transform: perspective(160vw) rotateX(-40deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(40vw);
}



.links a:hover {
  color:cyan;
}

#water{
  transform:translateY(-10%);
  color:blue;
  animation: fill 4s linear infinite;
  letter-spacing:1.5px;
}

.time,.future{
  letter-spacing:1.5px;
  color:white;
}

.future{
  font-size: 10vw;
  transform:translateY(90%);

}

.time{
  font-size:3vw;
}

#water2{

  animation: fill 4s linear infinite;
  letter-spacing:1.5px;
  color:cyan;
  transform:translateY(-3.4vw);
  font-size:3vw;
}

.container.active .futurediv{
  transform:translateY(-45vh);
}

.container.active .timediv{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Time</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar">
        <div class ="menu">
        <h1 class="logo">logo </h1>

        <div class ="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="menu-bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="background">
          <div class="background-blur">
            <div class="shadow1"></div>
            <div class="shadow2"></div>
            <div class ="middle">
              <div class="futurediv">

              <h2 class="future">Future is here</h2>
              <h2 class ="future" id="water">Future is here</h2>

              </div>

              <div class="timediv">
              <h2 class="time">"Time isn't the main thing.It's the only thing."</h2>
              <h2 class ="time" id="water2">"Time isn't the main thing.It's the only thing."</h2>
              </div>
              <a class="read-more" href="#" >Read more </a2>

                <div class="links">

                    <h2><a href="#">About</a></h2>

                    <h2><a href="#">Blog</a></h2>

                    <h2><a href="#">Services</a></h2>

                    <h2><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>

                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo here -

```
<a class="read-more" href="#" >Read more </a2>
```

It should be

```
<a class="read-more" href="#" >Read more </a>
```

This will remove blue lines.

.middle contains the other divs - and that is why stretches to accommodate all those and appear that wide.

Comment: so children can influence the size of the parent?